# Audio play sound Button problems in android

Tags: android, audio

I have 4 buttons, 2 are next and previous and other 2 are imgBut1 and imgBut2, by using 2 arrays i want to produce 2 different sound by click these image buttons but my sound is playing when i click on next and previous buttons, i want my sound is play only when i click on imgBut1 and imgBut2.
My java code:

```
 public class DoChashmiPics extends Activity {
         ImageButton imgBut1;
         ImageButton imgBut2;
         MediaPlayer ourSong1;
         MediaPlayer ourSong2;
         private int currentAudio = 0;

int[] audios1 = {R.raw.dochashm0,R.raw.dochashm1, R.raw.dochashm2, R.raw.dochashm3, R.raw.dochashm4, R.raw.dochashm5, R.raw.dochashm6, R.raw.dochashm7, R.raw.dochashm8, R.raw.dochashm9, R.raw.dochashm10, R.raw.dochashm11 };
int[] audios2 = {R.raw.dochashmi0,R.raw.dochashmi1, R.raw.dochashmi2, R.raw.dochashmi3, R.raw.dochashmi4, R.raw.dochashmi5, R.raw.dochashmi6, R.raw.dochashmi7, R.raw.dochashmi8, R.raw.dochashmi9, R.raw.dochashmi10, R.raw.dochashmi11 };


// my image button 1
public void imageButton1(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
  // my image button 2
public void imageButton2(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub             
}

// my next button
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
  currentAudio = (++currentAudio + audios1.length) % audios1.length;
  currentAudio = (++currentAudio + audios2.length) % audios2.length;
ourSong1 = MediaPlayer.create(DoChashmiPics.this, audios1[currentAudio]);
            ourSong1.start();
ourSong2 = MediaPlayer.create(DoChashmiPics.this, audios2[currentAudio]);
            ourSong2.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }

};
    // my previous button
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {           
    currentAudio = (--currentAudio + audios1.length) % audios1.length;
    currentAudio = (--currentAudio + audios2.length) % audios2.length;
ourSong1 = MediaPlayer.create(DoChashmiPics.this, audios1[currentAudio]);
            ourSong1.start();
ourSong2 = MediaPlayer.create(DoChashmiPics.this, audios2[currentAudio]);
            ourSong2.start();

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }

};
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your **mediaplayer** playing code in **image button**'s **event listener** then it will work

```
// my image button 1
public void imageButton1(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
ourSong1 = MediaPlayer.create(DoChashmiPics.this, audios1[currentAudio]);
            ourSong1.start();
ourSong2 = MediaPlayer.create(DoChashmiPics.this, audios2[currentAudio]);
            ourSong2.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }
}



// my image button 2
public void imageButton2(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
ourSong1 = MediaPlayer.create(DoChashmiPics.this, audios1[currentAudio]);
            ourSong1.start();
ourSong2 = MediaPlayer.create(DoChashmiPics.this, audios2[currentAudio]);
            ourSong2.start();

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }            
}

// my next button
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
  currentAudio = (++currentAudio + audios1.length) % audios1.length;
  currentAudio = (++currentAudio + audios2.length) % audios2.length;

};
    // my previous button
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {           
    currentAudio = (--currentAudio + audios1.length) % audios1.length;
    currentAudio = (--currentAudio + audios2.length) % audios2.length;

};
```

Comment: Thanks Chinmoy Debnath, i get thats i want.